# Chrome.storage.sync get overwritten when extension reload

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension which creates context menus with data gotten from an array stored in the chrome.storage.
This array is updated in the options.html page.

The context menu creator works fine, but when I open the options page and try to insert a new value into the array after reloading the extension it gets overwritten, losing the previous values.
¿Is there any solution?
**Edit 1**
For clarification.
The storage is kept, but when I try to push something into the array, it overwrites the whole array.

**Edit2**

**Options.html**

```
function save_options() {
    var id = document.getElementById('id').value;
    ids.push(id);

    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        'movieId': ids
    }, function() {
        // Feedback
        var status = document.getElementById('status');
        status.textContent = 'Options saved.';
        setTimeout(function() {
            status.textContent = '';
        }, 750);
    });
    createRow(1);
}
```

That is the code I use to upgrading the array.

Comment: Are you removing and re-adding the extension, or clicking the reload button on chrome://extensions?  Reload should keep chrome storage, whereas removing and re-adding would clear it.

Comment: I am reloading the extension, and closing chrome gives the same result.
The storage is kept, but when I try to push something into the array, it overwrites the whole array.

Comment: That sounds like you are incorrectly accessing the storage, it likely has nothing to do with reloading.  You'd have to provide details on how you are using the storage for anyone to help.

Comment: Where are you performing a `storage.sync.get` in order to fetch the ids from storage? If I had to guess you're doing `var ids = []` somewhere rather tna recreating them from storage.

Comment: Actually, I'm doing both, first `var ids = []` and later `storage.sync.get`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum you were right, I was cleaning the array, thanks for your help.

Comment: @cargide feel free to post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BenjaminGruenbaum said, I was doing `var ids = []` erasing the previous stored data. Just by erasing it, the code worked.